# Google Places returning building name

Tags: json, google-cloud-platform

I am using google to get address details. When searching it shows the full address, I am splitting this into different input fields using autocomplete.

For example using

```
route: 'long_name',
  postal_town: 'long_name',
  administrative_area_level_1: 'short_name',
```

I am able to get the house number no problem, but if its a building name it remains blank.
I would like to know how to get the building name please.

Below is an example of an input which autofills.

```
<input type="text" name="fromtown" id="postal_town" name="town_city" />
```

The input where the search of the place is shown below which shows the full address when clicked.

```
<input name="fromaddress" id="autocomplete" placeholder="Type pick up address" onFocus="geolocate()" type="text" class="form-control"/>
```